# Можно ли задать имя свойства объекта переменной ?(js)

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть переменные field, value и объект form :

```
 const field  = "title"
    const value  = "text"
    form ={                  //Могу ли я это реализовать?
      field : title 
    }
```

Comment: `form[field] = title; console.log(form);`

Answer (score 2):

Используя синтаксис ES6:

```
const field = "title";
const value = "text";
const form = {                  
  [field] : field  
};
```

http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames