# JavaScripts создание объекта с именем из переменной

Tags: javascript

Пример:

```
var name = 'hello';
var text = {name: 'nice'}
console.log(JSON.stringify(text));    // console: {"name":"nice"}
```

Как реализовать чтоб в название параметра прописалось содержимое переменной?
Для того чтоб получилось:

> {"hello":"nice"}

Comment: буквально на прошлой неделе -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/768555/223826

Comment: teran, Действительно вопрос такой же, но я так и не на гуглил его и решил задать свой. Снизу человек ответил, более подробно чем по ссылки. Так уж пусть весит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если среда, в которой исполняется этот код поддерживает ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), то можно воспользоваться так называемыми `computed properties` -  (вычисленные?) свойства. Для этого достаточно поместить имя переменной в квадратные скобки.

```js
var name = 'hello';    
var text = {[name]: "nice"};

console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
```

При этом, если такой переменной не существует, то имя свойства будет равно пустой строке.

Если же ES6 средой не поддерживается, то можно объявить необходимое свойство вне литерала объекта (тоже при помощи квадратных скобок):

```js
var name = 'hello';    
var text = {/* some other props */};
text[name] = "nice";

console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
```